# Is it true that $(AB)x = A(Bx)$ for two matrices $A$ and $B$ and a vector $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Just wondering if multiplying $AB$ first then $AB$ by $x$ is the same as multiplying $Bx$ the $A$ by $Bx$.

So $AB = M$ then $Mx$, or $Bx = N$ then $AN$.

Thanks.

Comment: yup, its associative

Comment: Awsome! Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you "multiply" vectors? Are you confusing vectors with matrices?

Comment: If you are using the scalar product for vectors, the answer is no

Comment: Sorry there was a typo I meant Matrices

Comment: Did you learn about linear operators yet?

Comment: I know their definition and that's about it

Comment: By choice of basis, we can identify linear operators and matrices. Composition corresponds to matrix multiplication and evaluation of linear operator at vector corresponds to multiplying matrix and column vector. So, $(AB)x = (A'\circ B')(x') = A'(B'(x')) = A(Bx)$, where ' means that we switched from matrix to operator and column vector to vector. The middle equality is how function composition is defined in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \in M_{m\times n}(K)$, $B\in M_{k\times m}(K)$ and $C\in M_{l\times k}(K)$.

Then,

\begin{align}
[(AB)C]_{ij} &= \sum_{r = 1}^k [AB]_{ir}[C]_{rj}\\ &= \sum_{r = 1}^k\left(\sum_{p = 1}^m [A]_{ip}[B]_{pr}\right)[C]_{rj} \\ &= \sum_{r = 1}^k \sum_{p = 1}^m [A]_{ip}[B]_{pr}[C]_{rj}\\ &= \sum_{p = 1}^m \sum_{r = 1}^k[A]_{ip}[B]_{pr}[C]_{rj} \\ &= \sum_{p = 1}^m [A]_{ip}\left(\sum_{r = 1}^k[B]_{pr}[C]_{rj}\right) \\ &= \sum_{p = 1}^m [A]_{ip}[BC]_{pj} = [A(BC)]_{ij}
\end{align}

and therefore, $(AB)C = A(BC)$.

Comment: C isn't a Matrix but thanks!

Comment: @klwar you can think of $C$ as a matrix with only one column, and the multiplication rule is still the same.

Comment: @klwar, Joppy is correct, in order to matrix act on a vector, you think of that vector as $n\times 1$ matrix, so called *column vector*. Action of a matrix is then just matrix multiplication.